# How to push a map to firebase database in typescript/cloud functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Notice on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) by switching between the `JAVA` and `NODE.JS` tab that pushing arrays of data to the database differ in the sense that `JAVA` uses a dynamic hashmap and `NODE.JS` is hard-coded into the script. The problem is I need to update a list of push ids and their children in a single update, so hard-coding them into the cloud function is not viable. How can I create a dynamic map to push to the firebase database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the JavaScript object that you pass to Realtime Database APIs any way you want.  The examples just show one way to do it for each platform.

These two bits of JavaScript yield exactly the same object:

```
const obj = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
}

const obj = {}
obj.foo = "foo"
obj.bar = "bar"
```

The end result in both cases is an object with two properties, foo and bar, and they have the same effect when passed to Realtime Database APIs.

Comment: How would I replace foo with a variable? obj.variable = "foo"

Comment: `obj[variable] = "foo"`  You might want to read up on how to deal with Objects in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: I bookmarked it. You're the man Doug. Thanks for the link. Will do.